# Zoom web SDK stuck on 'Joining Meeting'

Tags: reactjs, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate the Zoom Web SDK onto my React App, I went through their documentation and followed the steps of their Sample App, but however - When I try to join A meeting from my App, It is stuck on Joining Meeting. as you can see from the image below. My code is as follows

```
import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoomus/websdk';
ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();

ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();
ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib', '/av');
```

`

```
       ZoomMtg.init({
            leaveUrl: <my-url>,
            isSupportAV: true,
            success: (success) => {
           
              ZoomMtg.join({
                signature: <signature-from-api>,
                meetingNumber: <meeting-number>,
                userName: <my-username>,
                apiKey: <my-apiKey>,
                userEmail: <my-email>,
                passWord: <mypassword>,
                role: 0,
              
                success: (success) => {
                  console.log(success);
                },
                error: (error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              })
           
            },
            error: (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            }
          }) `
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue, it appears that the issue was caused by the ***role*** property on **ZoomMtg.join** object, after removing it, the issue was solved and I was able to join meetings.

Comment: I think your **ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib', '/av');** should come before **ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm(); and ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();**

Comment: Zoom Developer Advocate here, correct, the role property should be in the [Meeting SDK JWT token](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/auth/#generate-a-meeting-sdk-jwt) and not passed to the [join function](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/web/client-view/meetings/#prerequisites). We will improve the error messaging when passing in unexpected properties into the join function in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect the page and check for any errors in the network tab.
The following can be an issue:

1. meetingNumber -  your meeting number is not correct. Try giving a personal meeting number without any space.
2. signature- It better to generate a signature from the backend https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/build/signature .Signature may not be your issue right now but if you have multiple participants, there is a high chance you will get time out or other issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for that comment, but however, that was not the cause of the issue. I will update the correct answer.